# Captcha in SEDE sometimes doesn't appear

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha, anonymous-visitors

Captcha in SEDE sometimes doesn't appear:

[image]

The "I'm not a robot" challenge is not displayed. Instead, it should be:

[image]

Infrequent (<5%). Tested on Chrome+Win 10 as an anon user. I encountered the issue for the first time a few months ago at least.

Comment: Using a [site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Captcha+SEDE), I found [SEDE bug: Anonymous users asked to solve captcha, but captcha not shown](/q/347332), which is very similar (and perhaps also a duplicate). However, it seems the other issue happened every time for that user, and this other question also mentions that " "I'm not a robot" challenge is displayed ...", but you don't indicate that you got any dialog, including that challenge one.

Comment: FYI, I also found the somewhat similar, but quite old (from over 11 1/2 years ago) [Stack Exchange Data Explorer not fully working](/q/83239). However, about a month after posting the question, the OP answered that it was then working OK again.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  sorry, bad memory,  "I'm not a robot" challenge is *not* displayed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about this issue. It now means, at least to me, that the question I found from about 2 1/2 years ago, although it's quite similar, it's not a duplicate of yours.